# Filter customers collection by country id

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am getting customer collection by gender and name. I need to add filter by country id but country id of each customer locating in address collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', $post['firstname']);
        ->addAttributeToFilter('gender', $post['gender']);
        ->load();
```

So i need something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', $post['firstname']);
        ->addAttributeToFilter('gender', $post['gender']);

        ->addAttributeToFilter('country_id', $post['country_id']);//US
        ->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->addFieldToFilter('billing_country_id','US')
    ;
```